# Django says there are no changes to be made when I migrate

Tags: python, django, migration

I'm attempted to create a database for a fictional school. Unfortunatley when I try to migrate the tables this happens:

C:\Python34\Scripts\schoolDatabase>manage.py makemigrations school

C:\Python34\Scripts\schoolDatabase>python manage.py makemigrations school
No changes detected in app 'school'

This is the model I am referring to:

```
TYPE_OF_PERSON = (
('T', 'Teacher'),
('S', 'Student'),) 
DETENTION_COMPLETED = (
('Y', 'Yes'),
'N', 'No'
OUTCOME = (
('P', 'Pass'),
('F', 'Fail')
)
class Person:
first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 25)
surname = models.CharField(max_length = 25)
address = models.CharField(max_length = 45)
year_group = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
form = models.CharField(max_length = 15)
type_of_person = models.CharField(choices = TYPE_OF_PERSON)
person_id = models.CharField(primary_key = True)

class Subject:
name = models.CharField(max_length = 25)
class SchoolClass:
class_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key = True)
person_id = models.ForeignKey('Person')
subject = models.ForeignKey('Subject')
year_group = models.ForeignKey('Person')

class Attendance:
school_class = models.ForeignKey('SchoolClass')
date = models.DateField()
start_time = models.TimeField()
end_time = models.TimeField()
person_id = models.ForeignKey('Person')

class Assignment:
assignment_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key = True)
subject = models.ForeignKey('Subject')
school_class = models.ForeignKey('SchoolClass')
teacher = models.ForeignKey('Person')
description =models.TextField()
date_set = models.DateField()
due_date = models.DateField()
mark = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
comments = models.TextField()

class Detention:
detention_date = models.DateField()
student_id = models.ForeignKey('Person')
reason = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
completed = models.CharField(choices = DETENTION_COMPLETED)

class Exam:
exam_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key = True)
subject = models.ForeignKey('Subject')
paper = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
score = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
outcome = models.CharField(choices = OUTCOME)
```

I heard that if managed was set to False then Django won't create tables when you migrate, but I don't know how to set it to True.

When I typed in:

manage.py inspectdb it showed me that managed was set to False but how do I change it to True so that my database will be migrated?

Here is the traceback:

C:\Python34\Scripts\schoolDatabase>manage.py makemigrations school

C:\Python34\Scripts\schoolDatabase>python manage.py makemigrations school
No changes detected in app 'school'

```
                                                                                                                          class DjangoMigrations(models.Model):                              id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  # AutoField?       app = models.CharField(max_length=255)                         name = models.CharField(max_length=255)                        applied = models.DateTimeField()                                                                                              class Meta:                                                        managed = False                                                db_table = 'django_migrations'
```

Here is the tree:

[image]
[image]

Sorry about the poor formatting but stackoverflow won't let me put it in the code block.

Any help would be appreciated.

Settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS =[
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages.',
'django.contribe.staticfiles',
'school'
]
```

Comment: you have applied some migration before??? can you show the code of other migrations too??

Comment: No this is the first migration.

Comment: ok, show me your settings.py file, and your project tree, while try do it with `./manage.py makemigrations --initial school`

Comment: It says settings.py is too long by 3000 characters. And how do I show you the project tree?

Comment: via screenshot... you could attach images

Comment: It's complaining about the settings.py even when I put in <pre> </pre> so it was formatted properly.

Comment: ok... but just put the INSTALLED_APPS tuple or list...

Comment: I've added the tuple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your models should derive from models.Model:

```
 class Person(models.Model):
 ...
 class Subject(models.Model):
 ...
 ...
```